# Gmail/Imap Supports Compression?

Tags: mailkit

I found a link showing

Gmail supports the IMAP COMPRESS Extension (RFC4978), specifically the DEFLATE algorithm (RFC1951) aka zlib/gzip.

[Is it worthwhile using IMAP COMPRESS (DEFLATE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386268/is-it-worthwhile-using-imap-compress-deflate)

But when I enabled it says

The IMAP server does not support the COMPRESS extension.
Stack=System.NotSupportedException: The IMAP server does not support the COMPRESS extension.

Link must be wrong?

**Update:** Based on jstedfast request, we reran the compression after authentication.  We see these headers before authentication

> IMAP4rev1, Status, Quota, Idle, Namespace, Id, Children, Unselect,
>   SaslIR, XList, GMailExt1

and these after autentication

> IMAP4rev1, Status, Quota, Idle, Namespace, Id, Children, Unselect,
>   UidPlus, CondStore, ESearch, Enable, ListExtended, ListStatus,
>   SpecialUse, Move, UTF8Accept, LiteralMinus, AppendLimit, XList,
>   GMailExt1

And ImapCapabilities.Compress returns false.

We are using a free version of Gmail and not the gSuite.  Wonder if that is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that once we upgraded to the latest release of Mailkit Gmail Compression can be enabled and worked.  We were previously using 1.2.2

We have noticed that:

1. Protocol logging does not show the compressed data.
2. If you call service.Compress(token) more than once, gmail returns an error
3. One account was able to use gmail compression AFTER registering for 
   the Gmail API.  One offshore user is still not able to enable Gmail    compression. Event after registering for the API.

Comment: 'able to use gmail compression...' How? I cannot find any resources which mention Gmail mails can be compressed. I am trying by using 3rd party modules to compress email body and then send it

Answer (score 1):

After connecting to GMail's IMAP server, the capabilities are listed as:

> - CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH

After authenticating, the capabilities are:

> - CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584

Make sure that you authenticate first, and then you can try enabling compression.

Comment: Question: is this a for pay gmail account or a free one?